# Getting to grips with regex in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, expression

I'm trying to write a regular expression to match this line:
DD MONTH YEAR at HH:MM
as an example:
21 May 2009 at 19:09

So I have:
[0-30-9] for the day
[0-20-90-90-9] for the year
[0-90-9:0-90-9] for the time

I don't understand how to put these all together to form one single regex. I want to do

`if($string =~ /myregex/) {
}`

But can't form the entire thing. Also I don't know how to write a regex for the month, it has to match one of the 12 months of the year.

I am a Perl noob (this is my first day) and a regex noob, so help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the parts you have aren't quite correct. Instead of `[0-30-9]` I think you mean `[0-3][0-9]`, and similarly for the other numbers.

However, usually it suffices to be a little looser and just use `\d` which is equivalent to `[0-9]`.

You string the parts together one after the other:

```
/\d\d (MONTH) \d\d\d\d at \d\d:\d\d/
```

Which can be written more succinctly as:

```
/\d\d (MONTH) \d{4} at \d\d:\d\d/
```

Or if you really need it to be more strict as in your formulation:

```
/[0-3]\d (MONTH) [0-2]\d{3} at \d\d:\d\d/
```

I've left the month bit for last, since it is the more complicated bit. Again you can be loose or strict.

Loosely:

```
/[0-3]\d [A-Za-z]+ [0-2]\d{3} at \d\d:\d\d/
```

For a strict match we can use an alternation, each alternative is separated by a '|' and the list of choices is enclosed in parenthesis (although beware, parenthesis also have another extra meaning; don't worry it won't interfere in this case):

```
/[0-3]\d (January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December) [0-2]\d{3} at \d\d:\d\d/
```

Finally, if the day is not 0-padded (meaning the 1st is just '1' rather than '01') then you need to make that optional:

```
/[0-3]?\d (January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December) [0-2]\d{3} at \d\d:\d\d/
```

**Crib sheet**

- [] are used to create a character class, a set of matching characters
- \d is a built-in character class equivalent to [0-9]
- () are used to create a group, useful for delimiting an alternation (amongst other things)
- | is used to create alternation, a list of alternative character sequences that should be matched
- {n} is a modifier, saying exactly 'n' of the preceding character or character class should be matched
- + is a modifier, saying 1 or more of the preceding character or character class should be matched
- ? is a modifier, saying 0 or 1 of the preceding character or character class should be matched

Answer (score 2):

`[0-30-9]` doesn't do what you think it does. :)

`[0-3][0-9]` is what you're after. Similar steps for each of the other inputs...

`[0-3]?\d (Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) \d\d\d\d at [012]\d:[0-5]\d`

The `?` is to say the leading digit *might* be there.

The `\d` means 'digit', sometimes more legible.

`(foo|bar|baz)` is called 'alternation'.

The time is a problem :) This is good and simple, but would match a time like 29:59. Hehe. You could do this better with alternation: `(\d|1\d|2[0-3])` -- less legible but more correct.

And my advice for a Perl neophyte working with regexp is to *start small* and built them iteratively. It takes work. :)

Answer (score 0):

CPAN has some common Regexes in the Regexp::Common::* branch. For your case check out http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Regexp::Common::time .

Perhaps I should add, since you are so new to Perl, CPAN is Perl's collection of user-contributed modules for tasks. Many things that people may want to do have already been done before and collected for you. To install things you can do `sudo cpan modulename` (assuming you are on Linux, I'm sure you can find instructions for CPAN on mac and windows, but I don't know them).